# POST a form in which some element are file

Tags: javascript, angular, http

In a js web project,
I want to POST a form with a complexe json schema, and in which some field will be file.

How do I do It?

I currently upload a file alone like this

```
  const data = new FormData();
    data.append('mimetype', file.type);
    data.append('filename', file.name);
    data.append('file', file);
    return this.httpClient.post(url, data)
```

but I want my new form look like this:

```
 var data ={username:"John doe", 
    profilPhoto:{mimetype:..., filename:..., file: ...},
    house:{
       photo:{mimetype:..., filename:..., file: ...},
    },
    documents:[{mimetype:..., filename:..., file: ...}]

  }
```

Comment: Well JSON is not complex enough to store files. So this is impossible.

Comment: You have to use [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) to encode the file in Base64. After that, you can store the file in a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments encode your file to base64 then decode on the backend and save it as a blob.
Another option would be to use FormData as you do. For the array of objects, you can use JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse on backend.

```
  addFile(data:any): Observable<any> {
    const postData=new FormData();
    postData.append('username', data.username);
    postData.append('profilPhoto', data.profilePhotoFile);
    postData.append('house', data.houseFiles);
    postData.append('documents', JSON.stringify(data.documents);
    let API_URL = this.endpoint+`/add-file`;
    return this.http.post(API_URL, postData)
  }
```